# How to make axis ticks disappear in c3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, data-visualization, c3

I'm trying to remove the X and Y axis ticks and keep their corresponding values.

http://c3js.org/samples/simple_xy.html

So here I'd want to remove those little tick lines on the X and Y axis, but keep the values. What is the best way to proceed here? I couldn't find a way through the c3js config to change this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following CSS rule:

```
.tick line {
  display: none;
}
```